# Combine two methods and decrypt android assets with write

Tags: c++, encryption, android-ndk, openssl

How can i combine this two methods and make one smaller method and write decrypt file direct?

openssl decrypt cbc:

```
char *aes_decrypt_cbc(char *in, int inLen, int *outLen)
{
    unsigned char Key[AES_BLOCK_SIZE + 1];
    unsigned char ivec[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    AES_KEY AesKey;

    memset(Key, 0x00, sizeof(Key));
    memcpy(Key, AES_KEYCODE, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    memset(&AesKey, 0x00, sizeof(AES_KEY));
    if (AES_set_decrypt_key(Key, 128, &AesKey) < 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    memcpy(ivec, AES_IV, 16);

    char *out = (char *)calloc(inLen + 1, sizeof(char));
    if (out == NULL)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    AES_ecb_encrypt((unsigned char *)in, (unsigned char *)out, &AesKey, AES_DECRYPT);
    AES_cbc_encrypt((unsigned char *)in, (unsigned char *)out, inLen, &AesKey, ivec, AES_DECRYPT);

    int padLen = inLen;
    int padValue = out[padLen - 1];
    if ((padValue == 0) || (padValue > AES_BLOCK_SIZE))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    *outLen = padLen - padValue;
    out[padLen - padValue] = '\0';
    return out;
}
```

i use this code in my android app to extract assets file but i need to protect my assets file and app running time decrypt assets file and write in internal path,

```
int extract_file(JNIEnv *env, const char *szDexPath, const char *fileName)
{
    jobject ctx = getCTX(env);

    AAssetManager *mgr;

    jclass ApplicationClass = env->GetObjectClass(ctx);

    jmethodID getAssets = env->GetMethodID(ApplicationClass, "getAssets", "()Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;");

    jobject Assets_obj = env->CallObjectMethod(ctx, getAssets);

    mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, Assets_obj);

    AAsset *asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, fileName, AASSET_MODE_STREAMING);

    FILE *file = fopen(szDexPath, "wb");
    void *buffer = malloc(4096);
    while (true)
    {
        int numBytesRead = AAsset_read(asset, buffer, 4096);
        if (numBytesRead <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
       fwrite(buffer, numBytesRead, 1, file);
    }

    free(buffer);
    fclose(file);
    AAsset_close(asset);
    return 0;
}
```

i can not understand, how can i combine,
can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far youself?

Comment: I made changes many times, but this is not working.

Comment: i 60 min more fight with this code and successfully my problem solved.

Comment: Congratulations! Can you share with us how do you solve your problem?